# AParted partion re-do?

Tags: partitions

Can I re-size or adjust the size of the partitions that I made?  Or do I need to just start over from scratch?  I went through the process correctly several months back and now I would like to adjust the sizes of the partitions that I allocated.   I'm writing more to meet the standards of proper grammer.

Comment: Im not positive for each device, but I was successful in resizing a partition on my SD card several times. Hook to a PC and back everything up or make a Nandroid. When resizing dont make the partition with all your data smaller than it is, file tables and file integrity instabilities will happen. Also leave format intact (ie. Fat32). Plus note that resizing over different formats may cause instabilities as well or just not work.